# How to test my 1st In-App Purchase without releasing the App itself?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Ok, I suspect the answer to this is simple. But here goes...

I am in the process of submitting my app. I am submitting for review even though my In-App purchase integration has not been tested. This is essentially because I am unable to retrieve my list of IAP items if the IAP items have not been submitted/verified. So it seems to me this is like a "chicken or the egg" kind of situation.

My plan is to submit the App and the 1st IAP item. Then I am assuming this will allow me to magically retrieve the IAP item when I run the App.

Am I approaching this correctly, or is there a more intuitive/simpler way to test the IAP retrieval process (and the many other things to test once it is retrieved)?

Comment: You can test them in the sandbox environment.

Comment: But I am not able top retrieve the list of IAP items unless the App + the IAP are submitted. RIght?

Comment: The list will work and validate correctly in the sandbox environment if your IAP items are set up in itunes connect. They do not need to be approved yet and the app does not need to be submitted.

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar have you found a solution to this problem? we have the same issue. How can we test this if we cant even retrieve the IAP? I would assume this really needs a Binary that apple will approve right?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem for a new Mac app: created the app and IAP in App Store Connect, but not yet submitted. Product request does not return any In App purchases.

Answer (score 6):

Per [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/TestingInAppPurchases.html):

> To perform testing for in-app purchase products Set up test user
>   accounts within Users and Roles in iTunes Connect, as detailed in
>   [Creating Sandbox Tester Accounts](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SettingUpUserAccounts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH25-SW10) in [iTunes Connect Developer Guide.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/About.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225)
>
> You’ll need a test user for each territory you want to test the app
>   in.
>
> Clear any account information stored on your test device.
>
> In Settings, go to the Store settings. Click the Sign Out button. This
>   prevents an actual user account from automatically being used when
>   testing.
>
> Important: Don’t enter your test account information in the Store
>   settings panel. Doing so may invalidate your test account. Connect
>   your test device to your Mac.
>
> In Xcode, set your test device as your scheme’s destination.
>
> Open your app, and perform your in-app purchase product testing.
>
> Use your test account credentials to test the purchase.
>
> When your app uses the Store Kit API to request a payment, you’re
>   asked to sign in. Select Use Existing Account and enter your test
>   account user name and password. You are then asked to confirm the
>   purchase. The transaction completes.
>
> No financial transaction takes place, but a receipt is generated for a
>   successful transaction.

It's pretty straightforward, just takes a bit of set up. Good luck!

Comment: But will I be able to retrieve the list of IAP items from Apple? My understanding is that the App + IAP(s) need to be submitted before they are available for retrieval (i.e. testing).

Comment: You cannot retrieve a list of available IAP from Apple - they don't provide that service. If you need a dynamic list of product identifiers you are responsible for hosting and fetching that list.

Comment: BJHStudios - Sorry, I should clarify. I would like to test the retrieval of hosted IAP content(s). I understand that the list of the IAP items are something I need to bake into the app or retrieve from some external source.

Comment: Once you have registered your in-app purchases in iTunesConnect and they are waiting to be submitted and reviewed they are available for testing in the sandbox environment. They don't have to be approved first.

Comment: In Settings, go to the Store settings. Click the Sign Out button. This prevents an actual user account from automatically being used when testing. -> This is no more required, inside the Settings->iTunes Store and App Store area at the bottom you'll find Account Sandbox, this let you avoid sign out from current account. "Normal" account will be used with TestFlight instead.